# Emberjs - Knowing when model is rendered on template

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to know (with an event handler that would be the best) when the data from the model is render on the template, also when it's updated ?

I will use this as an example :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var promise = myNewModel();
        this._super(controller, promise);
    }
})
```

I am updating the modal in my setupController because I don't want the user to be stuck on a blank page.

Is there is a way to get that event when all the data are done rendering on the template, in my case when I have updated the model ?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you've reached `setupController`, the model needs to be a real one, not a promise. Setting the model here to be a promise is not going to work at all. You could try something like this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    myNewModel().then(function(model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    });
}
```

In other words, it's not an event you're looking for, it's your `newModel` call fulfilling.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine how I have done it, but I needed to modify the DOM from the view when my new model is actually render.

Comment: Well, that would be `didInsertElement` on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make use of Loading Substates. [Refer docs here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)

You need to fetch the model from the `route#model` hook and return a promise. The loading state will be triggered until the promise resolves. You can show a loading template until the promise resolves.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  var promise = myNewModel();
  return promise; 
 }
});
```

[Refer @machty's jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1399#/foo/bar/woot) and the related [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3568)